# UIPanGestureRecognizer UIView insertSubview belowSubview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uipangesturerecognizer

I have PanGestureRecognizer added for UIButton,
and i don't understand the following:

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
switch([recognizer state]){
    case  UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan: {
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [button setFrame:recognizer.view.frame];
        [button setBackgroundColor: [UIColor redColor]];

//      [self.view insertSubview:button belowSubview:recognizer.view];
        _tempButton = button;

    }break;
    case  UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged: {

        CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
        recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x, recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
        [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

    }break;
}
}
```

In this above example, everything goes well. Start. Stop. Drag from previous position.

But if i uncomment these rows

```
//      [self.view insertSubview:button belowSubview:recognizer.view];
```

something strange is happen.
1) Start dragging UIButton. The red uibutton is added to view.**NORMAL**
2) Stop dragging UIButton. This is **NORMAL**.
3) When i start dragging UIButton again from previous position (prev. step), a new button below red button is created, and this button starts moving as the origin button. And the button which i left after step 2 disappears. **STRANGE**

[image: first step, normal]
[image: second step, something strange]

Why?

Comment: Can you add the code where you added the `UIPanGesture` ?

Comment: using ib or without ib 
`UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)]; [_userBtn addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];`

Comment: I think it reference problem, somewhere the reference of buttons getting interchanged.